# Types Custom Field in WP Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use a custom field to define a variable in an array (more specifically, category), but the loop isn't reading the variable. I am using the Types WP Plugin to create custom fields/types.

I am printing the $cat variable I've defined as the class of the image I'm trying to pull just to double check that it does in fact work (it does!)

How should I be writing the $cat variable for the 'cat' argument in the array to be picked up?

```
<?php
$cat = types_render_field("which-gallery",   array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2"));
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'cat' => $cat,
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'desc',
'posts_per_page' => '-1',
'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID() ); 
echo "<img class='".$cat."' src='" . $image[0] . "'>";

endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: So what would be a solution to this, if any?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to print as the class value, its not clear from your post

Comment: I was only printing the class value in an effort to make sure that the custom field was being read and I had written the render_field correctly- the more important thing I'm trying to achieve is having the value of 'cat' equal the value of the rendered field.